# Question in the "First questions" queue, that was a user's second one

Tags: bug, specific-question, review

I have just reviewed [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4238497/164025) in the "First questions" queue that in reality was that user's second question on MSE (the truly first one being [from July 16th](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4199743/164025)). Is this a bug? If not, how should this behaviour be understood?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release .  Any of the first **three** questions / answers are considered "first".

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thanks, I posted that link as an answer, in order to close this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the announcement of the new review queues on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release): *"A user’s first few posts may require extra attention and to help new users get the hang of things, First questions and First answers will accept up to three posts per user if their first couple aren’t successful."*

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted twice.